STANDALONE NTP: ntpdate -d tells me the strata is too high
I've setup a standalone local ntp server on ubuntu to which ntp clients retrieve the time from it.
Server configuration:
# /etc/ntp.conf, configuration for ntpd; see ntp.conf(5) for help

driftfile /var/lib/ntp/ntp.drift

# Leap seconds definition provided by tzdata
leapfile /usr/share/zoneinfo/leap-seconds.list

# Enable this if you want statistics to be logged.
#statsdir /var/log/ntpstats/

statistics loopstats peerstats clockstats
filegen loopstats file loopstats type day enable
filegen peerstats file peerstats type day enable
filegen clockstats file clockstats type day enable

# Specify one or more NTP servers.

# Use servers from the NTP Pool Project. Approved by Ubuntu Technical Board
# on 2011-02-08 (LP: #104525). See http://www.pool.ntp.org/join.html for
# more information.

#server 192.1.1.125
server 127.127.1.0
fudge 127.127.1.0 stratum 10
# Use Ubuntu's ntp server as a fallback.
#pool ntp.ubuntu.com

# Access control configuration; see /usr/share/doc/ntp-doc/html/accopt.html for
# details.  The web page <http://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Support/AccessRestrictions>
# might also be helpful.
#
# Note that "restrict" applies to both servers and clients, so a configuration
# that might be intended to block requests from certain clients could also end
# up blocking replies from your own upstream servers.

# By default, exchange time with everybody, but don't allow configuration.
restrict -4 default kod notrap nomodify nopeer noquery limited
restrict -6 default kod notrap nomodify nopeer noquery limited

# Local users may interrogate the ntp server more closely.
restrict 127.0.0.1
restrict ::1

# Needed for adding pool entries
restrict source notrap nomodify noquery

# Clients from this (example!) subnet have unlimited access, but only if
# cryptographically authenticated.
#restrict 192.168.123.0 mask 255.255.255.0 notrust


# If you want to provide time to your local subnet, change the next line.
# (Again, the address is an example only.)
#broadcast 192.168.123.255

# If you want to listen to time broadcasts on your local subnet, de-comment the
# next lines.  Please do this only if you trust everybody on the network!
#disable auth
#broadcastclient

#Changes recquired to use pps synchonisation as explained in documentation:
#http://www.ntp.org/ntpfaq/NTP-s-config-adv.htm#AEN3918

#server 127.127.8.1 mode 135 prefer    # Meinberg GPS167 with PPS
#fudge 127.127.8.1 time1 0.0042        # relative to PPS for my hardware

#server 127.127.22.1                   # ATOM(PPS)
#fudge 127.127.22.1 flag3 1            # enable PPS API

Client Configuration:
server 10.1.1.55 iburst
#server 1.pool.ntp.org iburst

# Allow only time queries, at a limited rate, sending KoD when in excess.
# Allow all local queries (IPv4, IPv6)
restrict default nomodify nopeer noquery limited kod
restrict 127.0.0.1
restrict [::1]

But when I run ntpd -d 10.1.1.55 I get the following messages that tells me that the strata is too high
25 Jul 08:21:47 ntpdate[11276]: ntpdate 4.2.8p1@1.3265 Fri Jul 19 14:25:10 UTC 2024 (1)
Looking for host 10.1.1.55 and service ntp
host found : 10.1.1.55
transmit(10.1.1.55)
receive(10.1.1.55)
transmit(10.1.1.55)
receive(10.1.1.55)
transmit(10.1.1.55)
receive(10.1.1.55)
transmit(10.1.1.55)
receive(10.1.1.55)
10.1.1.55: Server dropped: strata too high
server 10.1.1.55, port 123
stratum 16, precision -24, leap 11, trust 000
refid [10.1.1.55], delay 0.02673, dispersion 0.00169
transmitted 4, in filter 4
reference time:    00000000.00000000  Thu, Feb  7 2036  6:28:16.000
originate timestamp: ea4ccef2.2a218a8a  Thu, Jul 25 2024 13:17:38.164
transmit timestamp:  ea4c89a1.e047b78b  Thu, Jul 25 2024  8:21:53.876
filter delay:  0.02759  0.02690  0.02724  0.02673
         0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000
filter offset: 17744.29 17744.28 17744.28 17744.28
         0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
delay 0.02673, dispersion 0.00169
offset 17744.287454

25 Jul 08:21:53 ntpdate[11276]: no server suitable for synchronization found

Don't really know where to start debugging it.

This question is similar to: ntpdate -d Server dropped Strata too high. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You haven't configured it to fudge the server, only to fudge the client.
Replace
server 127.127.1.0
fudge 127.127.1.0 stratum 10

with
fudge server 127.127.1.0 stratum 10

